# How to make top layer's (div) background "holey" so I could manipulate bottom layer's (div) content?

Tags: css, html

I have 2 divs. I put them one on each other. So there are 2 layers. On the second layer I have iframe youtube video and photo gallery. The thing is that first layer (top div) doesn't allow me to click on "play" or "next pic" that is in second div. Is it possible to make fist div background "holey"?

Btw, I really need that top layer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css:

```
 pointer-events:none;
```

for top layer

Comment: That's it! That's what I was searching! Thank you alot.